# problem setting specified view to landscape mode

Tags: iphone, landscape

I did look for possible answers but found none. my problem is that I only want one of the views in my app (which shows an image) to be in both portrait and landscape mode, while other views in portrait only.

this view is added to `[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window]` as its subview.

and i set return YES in `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation`

and also `[self.view setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];` in `- (void)viewDidLoad`

but when i turn the device the view doesn't rotate. please tell me where i did wrong or what more needs to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, a subview (such as the one you added) is only sent the message saying the device has rotated if the owning container view passes it along.  If you use a UINavigationController or UITabBar and add your view to that it is done for you, but if you add the view directly to the window as you have it isn't.

EDIT: you can capture the device orientation changing yourself using  [UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html#//apple_ref/c/data/UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification) with NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: Thank you Ben, i tried add it to my [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] tabBarController].view but it doesn't work either. maybe because the tabBarController view is also a subview of window?

Comment: Ah, sorry I wasn't that clear. It'll only auto-rotate correctly if you add it to the tab bar controller using - (void)setViewControllers:(NSArray *)viewControllers animated:(BOOL)animated, not if you just add as a subview. I haven't tried it myself, but I think capturing the UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification inside your custom viewcontroller is a good thing to try.

Comment: what should i do in the selector method? is there any method i can call to rotate the view? or i have to transform the view with code like CGAffineTransformRotate?